# Copy Separate List of numbers in a single row from Linux text file to excel columns

Tags: excel, linux, unix

I have a text file in my linux system which has multiple rows and columns with numbers such as

[image]

How do I copy these numbers to excel sheet such that each row and column nicely fits in the cells ? Currently when I copy I see something like this where all values in row aren't copied to different cells. I would like to see each value in row in different columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Past the data
2. Click on the raised icon (text import wizard) [image]
3. Choose `Delimited` and click `Next`
4. Past in the `Other` field delimiter from you string between columns of data
5. Click `Finish`